# How to authenticate SignalR handshake with client in ReactJS

Tags: signalr

I have a Reactjs client which is making handshake with SIgnalR HUb to get continuous data from server to client. I wanted to ensure we have some authentication while the client makes the handshake. Any ideas on this would be really appreciated.